DAX: Revenue, Expansion, Reduction, Churn... how to implement?
I have the following sample data coming from Power Query:

What I need to acomplish is, based on the revenue for each client in the previous month, to decompose the revenue into Expansion, Recurrent and New Customer:
Expansion: A client had some revenue in the previous month and a higher revenue in the given month, so the expansion would be the difference.
Recurrent: The minor value between the revenue in the given month and the revenue in the previous month
New Customer: A client had no revenue in the previous month and some revenue in the given month, so new customer value would be the revenue in the given month.
Also, I need to look at the lost revenue, decomposed into Reduction and Churn:
Reduction: A client had some revenue in the previous month and a lower revenue in the given month, so the reduction would be the difference.
Churn: A client had some revenue in the previous month and no revenue in the given month, so the reduction would be the difference (or the revenue in the previous month).
So, in february, I would have these values:

I tried many variations of Dax Measures, but for each variation something did not work: I had no totals, the totals were wrong, the calculation was wrong... a total madness.
I would appreciate some support from the community. Thanks in advance!
Update: As requested, some examples of DAX that I already tried:
Total Revenue = sumx(summarize(Receita,Receita[Client],'Calendar'[Year Month]),sum(Receita[Revenue]))

Previous Month Revenue = sumx(summarize(Receita,Receita[Client],'Calendar'[Year Month]),CALCULATE(SUM(Receita[Revenue]),DATEADD(Calendar[Date], -1, MONTH)))

Expansion = if(and(Receita[Total Revenue]>Receita[Previous Month Revenue],not(isblank(Receita[Previous Month Revenue]))),Receita[Total Revenue] - Receita[Previous Month Revenue],blank())


Update your question with one or two of the closet DAX measures that you have tried. It will help to identify issues/improvements. You should also look to split the Client column in Power Query so the parenthesis is in a separate column.

Please show what the output would be, and it's always easier if you include sample data as a  Mark down table rather than expecting someone else to copy your screenshot.
